# My local maven repository looks strange. all jar, pom files newly downloaded are all jfrog html files, what happend to me?

Tags: maven, jar, repository, local, pom.xml

One day before, I tried to install artifactory trial version in my local mac pc.
And then, tried Nexus solution for comparison.

And after then, my local maven repository looks really strange..

All newly downloaded jar and pom files are all jfrog home page html.
almost every file's size are 17KB or 18KB.

So, I cannot update any jar file, and so cannot create new web instances...
all dependencies are broken.

I cannot understand what happend to my maven system.

Comment: I don't know the reason. Some jar files were normal jar files, but some jar files, like common-io or spring-mvc, were jfrog site html.

Comment: So I tried to install local nexus repository server, and then setting the xml like http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html. After then, delete abnormal jar files in my local maven.

Comment: and problems look like soved. and then what was problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your Artifactory server URL is incorrect. For any incorrect prefix URL of artifactoryonline.com the request is forwarded to jfrog.com homepage.